# Ros2 with docker - dev setup

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,  I'm new to ROS and seeking some advice for my dev setup.

- M1 Mac
- Ros2 Humble

So, I'm using docker to run ros on my mac. I dont want to rebuild the image after every little change, therefore I thought docker-compose would be good (for development). Also, I'm running a little container for getting the screen out (vnc).

Here is the current setup: https://github.com/RobinHeitz/ros2-docker-testing

What works great:
I can "work" (like create packages etc.) within the living container and see the changes within VSCode -> Great for development.

But:
Seems like `docker-compose exec ros bash` is launching some new container or something like that, because I can't see a publishing message in another terminal tab (again, with `docker-compose exec ros bash`).

I know its not a clear question, but I want know if this setup *could* work and what I have to change to access the running container and see nodes/ topics from other terminal tabs.

If Its *bad*, then I might need a hint in the right direction.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411306/ros2-with-docker---dev-setup/) by [robin_rob96](https://answers.ros.org/users/77028/robin_rob96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2023-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some tutorials and templates for working with ROS2 in the VS Code with Docker set up, I suggest you to check them out: https://www.allisonthackston.com/articles/vscode-docker-ros2.html and https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-vscode-docker-set-up/16293

The part of your question with the option to see topics from other terminal tabs is interesting - I would also like to see an explanation how to do it.

Other sources I found:

- https://github.com/devrt/ros-devcontainer-vscode
- https://erdalpekel.de/?p=219

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2023-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With docker you use the

```
docker exec -it <containername> bash
```

command to get access to the tty session within the container.

I created a video on how to setup ROS2 within a docker container, from scratch here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03wKo-riJlA

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [kevsmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/134556/kevsmac/) with karma: 21 on 2023-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robin_rob96](https://answers.ros.org/users/77028/robin_rob96/) on 2023-01-27**:
I don't get it - it does not work...
I tried the following both, for a custom container and the official osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full image:

I start the container with `docker -it run` and start to publish on a topic or run a node.

In a second terminal window, i run `docker exec -it <name/ ID> bash`.
I get into the running container (I guess, but there is not error).
After sourcing opt/ros/ I can't see any node started before nor the topic I'm currently publishing to.

For me it seems like I'm in a different container (?) but with `docker container list` i see, that there is only 1 running...

What am I doing wrong?
Hope you can help me :S

**Comment by [robin_rob96](https://answers.ros.org/users/77028/robin_rob96/) on 2023-01-28**:
**I fixed the 'problem' finally.**

So, I was using the image `osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full` which seems to be official, at least for me (watching the docker-hub page).

With the image `ros:humble` everything works as it should...